# Password Displayed on inputSecret too long

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, seam

I Use JSF 1.2 and i want to display a password as six characters for the user, and since i use an md5 encryption, so the password is displayed too long.

This is my code

```
<h:inputSecret  id="password"
               redisplay="true"           
              value="{userHome.instance.password" 
                    style="FONT-SIZE: medium;" title="Password">     
                          </h:inputSecret>
```

Thks a lot

Comment: How do you decide what 6 characters a password is turned into?  The first 6 characters of its md5 hash?  Sounds pretty useless.

Comment: The value take all the md5 encryption of the password, so it's not presentable. there is a way to minimise the length of the value and preserve the original value to be setted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only apply MD5 hashing at the point the data is to be saved in the DB, not before.

You should not obtain the password from the DB whenever you present an edit form to the enduser. You should keep the field empty.

Comment: I use Informix as an dbms so i cannot apply MD5 hashing with MD5(password) on database as in mysql

Comment: Just do it *right* before the data is to be saved in the DB. I.e. when all validation passes and the bean's action method is about to persisting the entity. If you're using EJBs and/or DAOs, do it right there. Create if necessary a second property which is basically a md5 of the first property. Use the first property in view only and the second for DB only, but that is not necessary if the business and persistence logic is doing its job fine.